# Retrieve large data over 200 MB from db JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Is there any better way to retrieve data in chunks instead of whole at a time and paginate them? I'm trying to retrieve large data over +300k rows (200 MB) using JdbcTemplate queryForList and return a paginated response for my API. I couldn't find any feasible column name to sort the data per my needs thus used ronum record_num. Below is my code.

```
final String sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, rownum record_num FROM (SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE MONTH = ? AND YEAR=?)a)"; 
List<Map<String, Object>> list = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, month, year);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use `rownum` pseudocolumn and wrapping query. If you want to read rows 10-20 (do note `rownum` starts from 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT *, rownum r FROM tableName WHERE month = ? AND year = ? ) 
WHERE r > 10 AND r <= 20
```

However if you are on Oracle 12c or newer you can use new `OFFSET` statement which [database should optimize to skip reading redundant rows](https://dba-presents.com/index.php/databases/oracle/31-new-pagination-method-in-oracle-12c-offset-fetch):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE month = ? AND year = ?
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I tried the exact code 1, unfortunately I got empty result

Comment: @roj updated the answer, try adding row as a column first, so it's calculated. I'm not sure if this requires one more wrapping query or not.

Comment: thanks! Just a quick question, does Oracle assign the same rownum to a row each time. For example, if i run a query to get 1- 5000 rows, then second query to 5000 - 1000 rows and so on till the last row. Do I get unique rows on all occasions?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question has been tagged with `spring-boot`, I am assuming your are using spring-boot in some capacity. Why don't you consider using spring data JPA?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This will allow you to use the `Repository` infrastructure. Then you would be able to use `PagingAndSortingRepository`. That will allow you to access your results in a paged way. Here's the [reference material](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).